# Cassandra - CqlEngine - using collection

Tags: collections, cassandra, cql

I want to know how I can work with collection in cqlengine
I can insert value to list but just one value so I can't append some value to my list
I want to do this:
In CQL3:

```
UPDATE users
SET top_places = [ 'the shire' ] + top_places WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

In CqlEngine:

```
connection.setup(['127.0.0.1:9160'])
TestModel.create(id=1,field1 = [2])
```

this code will add 2 to my list but when I insert new value it replace by old value in list.

The only help in Cqlengine :
  https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/columns.html#collection-type-columns

And I want to know that how I can Read collection field by cqlengine.
Is it an dictionary in my django project? how I can use it?!!

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example it's a list.

Given a table based on the Cassandra CQL documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE plays (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    game text,
    players int,
    scores list<int>
)
```

You have to declare model like this:

```
class Plays(Model):
        id = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
        game = columns.Text()
        players = columns.Integer()
        scores = columns.List(columns.Integer())
```

You can create a new entry like this (omitting the code how to connect):

```
Plays.create(id = '123-afde', game = 'quake', players = 3, scores = [1, 2, 3])
```

Then to update the list of scores one does:

```
play = Plays.objects.filter(id = '123-afde').get()
play.scores.append(20) # <- this will add a new entry at the end of the list
play.save()            # <- this will propagate the update to Cassandra - don't forget it
```

Now if you query your data with the CQL client you should see new values:

```
 id       | game  | players | scores
----------+-------+---------+---------------
 123-afde | quake |       3 | [1, 2, 3, 20]
```

To get the values in python you can simply use an index of an array:

```
print "Length is %(len)s and 3rd element is %(val)d" %\
 { "len" : len(play.scores), "val": play.scores[2] }
```

Comment: thanks so much, So we should read the record to memory then add some new values to it. Thanks that's was so useful and I hope that cqlengine can support it internally ( no need to read and do it in memory) as cql3 can do it.

Comment: "Blind updates" https://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/queryset.html#blind-updates support server-side merge of collection changes through `%ATTRIBUTE%__%COMMAND%` (two underscores) feature.